# Calculate directory size: Better through DirectoryInfo or storing size of files on database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

We have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app in wich our users have the possibility to upload files to a folder.

Now we want to limit the size of this folder to avoid it to grow uncontrolled.

To do this would be fine to account the current size of the folder, so when a file is going to be uploaded we can check if the fixed size limit would be reached and cancel the upload.

Problem is we fear this could slow a lot our upload process as number of files into source directory grow.

We could use DirectoryInfo to build a method that retrieves folder size, or we could store on database the size of each uploaded file (we are already storing their paths, as they are related to other elements on our business model) and build a method that retrieves the folder size adding the values stored on database.

Wich method will be better and faster?

Comment: Depending on the number of files the Database option will probably be the quickest, but also, how slow do you think the DirectoryInfo would become? If it's nothing more than 2-3 seconds I wouldn't imagine people being bothered about that when uploading a file

Comment: @Nunners it also causes a lot of IO which may slow down the rest of the IO - if that is more than a "dump files never to be used" that easily may be a bottleneck.

Comment: if it is not that critical in form of it should be higher than 4.2mb or sth like this and your files are having sort of similarity in size (they are all around 500kb for example) then just get number of files in directory and multiply it by 500kb for example.

Answer (score 2):

I vote for storing the size of folder in DB. If you use `DirectoryInfo` it could be return incorrect info in case there is someone is uploading file. Storing in DB will give you exactly the current number no matter there are anyone uploading files.

Comment: +1. You need to keep the files in the database anway for selection and a lot of other things (like tagging) unless your application is trivial - storing the size in there is a small additional piece of information. DirectoryInfo can take some serious time once you have a lot of files.

Comment: As TomTom said, DB values would propably be faster in the long run and could enable caching in a bigger application.

Answer (score 0):

If you just get the folder size I think get directory size from database not good..because after upload  any file you must update your database and for check limittion must  get directory size from database ...but with a method that get directory info size is easier and has good performance

Comment: Good performance? Let me guess - you never dealt with that method on a real file server, right? Lets say with a million files. The needs to update the database anyway. Which means your plus points do not exist anyway.

Comment: @TomTom if we want add directory size in database we must get it with method and store it in database...if the directory size change you must update your database ... you must work with method and database ...is it good??

Comment: Unless he has a pure file manager he will anyway manage information in the database. Tags, comments etc. - so the database has to be asked anyway. The overhead of storing a single number (size of afile) in the database in addition to that is neglegible.

Comment: @M.Azad I think you misunderstand the OP slightly, he is talking about storing each individual File Size, and then writing a query to get the sum of that depending on the folder. He wouldn't have to recalculate the entire folder size everytime.

Comment: @TomTom If Folder size limitation changed ...is database information about folder size true?

Comment: @M.Azad Use your brain? If you store file sizes in the database they will not magically change.

Comment: @TomTom yes.as an example  imaging my folder limitation is 10mb.I upload a file that is 5mb first i check folder limitation and it is ok to upload file ... after upload my limitaton changed it now 5mb if i want upload a file more than 5m it must be cancel...I  say after upload a file how you can calculate your folder limitation?

Comment: @M.Azad You use your brain and come up with specifications? You never calculate the limiation, you set it. And you as programmer define what happens in the process when an upload goes over the limit. THis is so totally the same in both cases that the question is irrelevant to the question asked here.

Comment: @TomTom please thinking next answer me...in my example after upload a file that is 5mb. for next time I upload a file..how you check limitation for this file and how accept or cancel  it?

Comment: @M.Azad You program it? Or hire a programmer to do it`? This is a trivial question and the solution depends on business requirements.

Comment: @TomTom The business requirement is clear:when a file is going to be uploaded we can check if the fixed size limit would be reached and cancel the upload. so what's your solution for my example?

Comment: Doing YOUR job or hiring a consultant. Start with a flow diagram. Then program. This is the type of problem I would hit a junior developer in an interview with.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the speed of enumerating files depends on how much files are in this folder.
Do you know this figure?

You can run this from command line and it will create you 5000 files

```
For /L %i in (1,1,5000) do fsutil file createnew A%i.tmp 12000
```

And then make a performance test.